# Multi-line textbox shows mult-line string as One-Line

Tags: c#, string, textbox, multiline

I am making a program where you enter an item's name and it's description. Then you add it to a listbox and after you are done you can save all the items to a 'txt' file. (Using StreamWriter). This program also has an edit button that allows you to edit the description in the listbox by removing it first from the listbox and then showing it back in the textbox (, so you can edit it)

If the description is multi-line, it will successfuly show it multi-line when I select it in the listbox and click the edit button that will show it back in the textbox. **BUT if I save all the items in the listbox to a file first**. And then open up the file again so it load the items back into the listbox. And then clicking the edit button...

The multi-line description will show as a one-line description in the textbox.

I am not sure why - but I've also made a label that will show the exact string that the textbox is suppose to show and the label is showing it multi-lined while textbox isn't!

**The string is definitely multi-line but the multi-line textbox is showing it one-line after loading the items back into the listbox using StreamReader.**

Example of the multi-line string: (named "theString1")

> This is line 1
>
> This is line 2

Using the following code: `TextBox1.Text = theString1;` this appears in the text box:

> This is line1This is line2

But if I use the same code with a label. It will show it correctly.

**If someone can explain to me why this is happening I will be more than happy. I just need an explanation.**
Thanks in advance.

---[More info]---

**Just so you know. I came up with this code myself so it is probably set-up all wrong.**
I will be happy if you tell me a better way to do this.

I am using a list to store the description text + the item name. I seperated these two using '`' .And splited the string (see code).

This is the code that happens when you click the edit button. It removes the item from
the listbox and shows it in the textbox so you can edit it and add to listbox again:

```
int index = listBox.SelectedIndex;

itemName.Text = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

var descVar = descList.ElementAt(index).Split('`');   
string theString1 = descVar[1];  

TextBox1.Text = theString1;
```

This is how it saves it to a file:

```
FileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
save.Title = "Save information...";
save.DefaultExt = "Text File|*.txt";
save.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";

if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{

    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(save.FileName);

    foreach (string s in listBox.Items)  //This writes the names of item names.
    {
        sw.WriteLine(s);
    }

    sw.WriteLine("`1`");  //I use this to seperate the item names from description.

    foreach (string s in descList)  //This writes the descriptions that are stored in a list named "descList".
    {
        sw.WriteLine(s);
        sw.WriteLine("``");     //I use this to seperate descriptions from each other because they are multi-line.
    }
    sw.WriteLine("`2`");   //Just something so I know where it ends. :D
    sw.Close();              
}
else
{
}
```

And this is how it loads: (This can definitely be better!)

```
FileDialog load = new OpenFileDialog();
load.Title = "Load information...";
load.DefaultExt = "Text File|*.txt";
load.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";

if (load.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    List<string> loadDesc = new List<string>();  //Don't ask you will see why
    descList.Clear();

    while (listBox.Items.Count > 0)  //This removes all items in the listbox to load new ones.
    {
        int index = 0;
        listBox.Items.RemoveAt(index);

        descList.Clear();


        itemName.Text = "";
    }  

    StreamReader rw = new StreamReader(load.FileName);
    for (; true; )  
    {
        string read = rw.ReadLine();

        if (read == "`1`")  //When it reaches the separator I made it stops reading.
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(read);
        }
    }

    for (; true; )  
    {
        string read = rw.ReadLine();

        if (read == "`2`")
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            loadDesc.Clear();
            loadDesc.Add(read);
            for (; true; )       //Please tell me if this can be done differently.
            {
                string read2 = rw.ReadLine();
                if (read2 != "``")           //This will keep reading the whole description until it reaches the separator.
                {
                    loadDesc.Add(read2);     //Adds each line into the list I created.
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            string oneBigString = string.Join("\n", loadDesc);   //This basically converts all strings in a list into one string.
            descList.Add(oneBigString);                          //And this finally add the string to the main list from where it then loads.
        }
    }

}
else
{
}
```

I believe that is it. 
If there is anything else you need - tell me.

Comment: show us how the string is constructed, how you're saving it to the file, and how you're reading it from the file

Comment: and show the textbox code as well, are you adding <asp:TextBox id="tbox" TextMode="multiline" runat="server" />

Comment: Please don't repeat tags in question titles.

Comment: Textbox is multi-line. I set that in the properties.

Comment: The textbox does not have any code to show you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string oneBigString = string.Join("\n", loadDesc);` is where the issue is.

Use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `\n`

I'm also just going to go over a couple of things that could be improved with your code (there are a lot, but I just want to cover a couple).

`while (listBox.Items.Count > 0)  //This removes all items in the listbox to load new ones.`

You don't need to iterate over every element in the listbox to remove it. You can just do listBox.clear()

Also, using break to get out of loops is generally bad practice. This should be written as...

```
for (; true; )  
{
    string read = rw.ReadLine();

    if (read == "`1`")  //When it reaches the separator I made it stops reading.
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        listBox.Items.Add(read);
    }
}
```

this

```
string read = rw.ReadLine()
while(read != "`1`")  
{
   listBox.Items.Add(read);
   read = rw.ReadLine()
}
```

but theres more, what if `1` is never found in the file? It would crash your program, so you also need to check if there is more data to be read...

```
string read = rw.ReadLine()
while(read != "`1`" && !sw.EndOfStream)  // Make sure you're not at the end of the file
{
   listBox.Items.Add(read);
   read = rw.ReadLine()
}
```

Comment: @AdamVeselič There is a white checkmark near the top of my answer on the left. If this answer was correct please click it so its green to mark it as the accepted answer :)